# create cron job in linux without crontab -e

Tags: rhel, cron

I want to use the cron in the linux redhat 7 in order to run some jobs

**but I not want to use the crontab -e** , since some users can change my conf

so I did the following example

```
cd /etc/cron.d
vi test
* * * * echo test >/tmp/test


more test
* * * * echo test >/tmp/test
```

so I wait one min to see the log - /tmp/test

ut log /tmp/test not created

why ?

what is wrong with my cron ?

```
ls -ltr
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  29 Aug  1 18:50 test
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "some users may change my conf"?

Comment: @Kusalananda I suspect the account is shared (known to) several different people and using `/etc/cron.d` isolates his script under root's control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `crontab` has only four time and date fields. You need five to be valid.

If you are placing your script in `/etc/cron.d` you need to add the username that will execute the script as the first field following the standard time and date ones; like:

```
* * * * * yael echo test > /tmp/test
```

See `man 5 crontab`